# why is include_path in php.ini being ignored?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a zend library and for simplicity I put it in the root. (`/library/zend/...`)
I added the path to my `php.ini` `include_path` and un-commented it. (`include_path = ".:/library/"`
).

In my website files I have `require_once 'Zend\Loader.php';`

But when I try to access the page I get:

```
 Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader.php): failed to open stream: 
          No such file or directory  in /var/www/TEST/index.php on line 7

 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader.php' 
    (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') 
    in /var/www/TEST/index.php on line 7
```

Why is it looking for pear? Those directories do not even exist.

I have required the full path and that worked (well then zend didnt know where to look for everything else but it was able to find loader.php) so I think that means permissions are okay.
I have tried adding/removing a trailing slash in the include path and a preceding slash in the php website file.

The only thing i could find on google was something about a .htaccess? Not sure what or where that is.

I am editing the right `php.ini` file because i am able to turn error reporting on and off from it.

Both doc_root and include_path have been changed but fail to show changes in phpinfo() even though phpinfo() says i am editing the right php.ini file

Comment: You have to use the absolute path from your root of the filesystem to your library!

Comment: If you're using absolute paths in your require/include calls, then the include_path is **NOT** checked, because you're telling PHP exactly where the file is.

Comment: `phpinfo()` could tell which additional ini-files are parsed, apparently, something is _overwriting_ your `include_path`.

Comment: The include path you entered is not in the include path shown the error, so it's being overridden somewhere. Can you see if there's anything include path related in `public/index.php` if you have one?

Comment: I only used the absolute (this just means full path right?) to test permissions. I will be leaving it as require_once 'Zend\Loader.php';. Nothing in my files are overwriting the include path but these ini files are also being loaded: etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-gd.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini...

Comment: where would I find the public/index.php ? my index file is currently in a sub-directory of /var/www/ so i get a list of files when i visit my server over a browser..

Comment: After editing you php.ini, did you restart Apache ?

Comment: Yes, just reinstalled php5 will see if that helps.. it did not help. I have also just realized the doc_root will also not change even though i changed it!

Comment: The error message in your question gives an absolute path (`/Zend/Loader.php`) which does not match the `require_once` example you gave. Can you edit your question to the actual error you're getting and the code that is causing it?

Comment: Tim I fixed it. The inconsistency was from me adding and removing slashes thinking it might help. The absolute path for the Loader is /library/Zend/Loader.php which is why the relative path is Zend/Loader.php if the include_path is set to /library

Comment: temp fix for anyone with this problem: copy library into /usr/share/php/. So the library path should look like /usr/share/php/zend/...

I still need help with what is overwriting/why parts of php.ini are being ignored though because I also need to change doc_root

Answer (score 0):

When you change the `include_path` in php.ini the change will affect all your projects.

Better idea would be to use `set_include_path` and `get_include_path` php functions to update the path just for the current application.

Remember, that *the path must be an absolute path*,
so this will be more or less like this:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/../vendor/',
    get_include_path(),
)));
```